# Is there a maximum rep gained from suggested edits on beta sites?

Tags: support, reputation, edits, suggested-edits, beta-sites

On main sites there is a [max of 1000 (1k)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/252153) rep from suggested edits (so 500 suggestions). On beta sites, however, the Editing Priv is 500.

So can I get to that priv *just* by editing, or is the 1000 max rep not 1000 on beta sites (maybe 250, as that's half way as well)?

Comment: Note that on any site it should probably be possible to reach the suggested-edit rep cap by editing enough wikis... although not necessarily practical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doesn't differ anywhere.

It's 1k on public beta (editing privs at 1k) and launched sites (editing privs at 2k), for private betas also, which would be, however, more difficult to achieve, as they have the full editing privileges at just 500 rep plus the fact that typically you wouldn't find so low-quality private beta :p.

And yes, I personally woundn't suggest getting 1k *just* by editing, but you can try ;D

Comment: If you hit 500 rep and gain editing privileges, but then lose them later because the site goes into a different phase or you post a bounty, you'll resume earning edit reputation until you hit the 1000 max.

Comment: @Tro that's why I didn't say it is impossible :D